# Python Tkinter sprite movement slows down when I have a background image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using a Canvas in tkinter to move images around the screen using key binds. When I have a background image, the movement slows way down. If I remove the background image, the movement speeds up and acts as I intended it to.
I have been using tkinter for a few years now and this seems like a new problem. I am using PyCharm on a Mac.

I tried removing the background and the speed of the movement was fast and fluid. When I added the background back in, the speed of the movement slowed down and became sluggish.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
# Creating the canvas
playground = Canvas(window, height=1500, width=1500, bg="green")
playground.pack()

# When this background is removed, the movement of the image is 
fluid and smooth
bgImg = PhotoImage(file="pacbg.png")
bg_Img = bgImg
bg = playground.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=bgImg)

# The image I move with key binds
pmanImg = PhotoImage(file="pac.png")
pman_Img = pmanImg
pman = playground.create_image(100, 100, image=pmanImg)


# Moving the image to the right
def fluidright(event):
    global rightLoop, leftLoop
    try:
        window.after_cancel(leftLoop)
        playground.move(pman, 10, 0)
        rightLoop = window.after(10, lambda: fluidright(event))
    except NameError:
        playground.move(pman, 10, 0)
        rightLoop = window.after(10, lambda: fluidright(event))


# Stopping the right motion
def stopright(event):
    global rightLoop
    window.after_cancel(rightLoop)

# Moving the image to the left
def fluidleft(event):
    global rightLoop, leftLoop
    try:
        window.after_cancel(rightLoop)
        playground.move(pman, -10, 0)
        leftLoop = window.after(10, lambda: fluidleft(event))
    except NameError:
        playground.move(pman, -10, 0)
        leftLoop = window.after(10, lambda: fluidleft(event))

# Stopping the left motion
def stopleft(event):
    global leftLoop
    window.after_cancel(leftLoop)


# My key binds
playground.bind_all("<Right>", fluidright)
playground.bind_all("<Left>", fluidleft)
playground.bind_all("<KeyRelease - Right>", stopright)
playground.bind_all("<KeyRelease - Left>", stopleft)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't guess what you might be doing wrong without seeing a small example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited to include a simple example. When I remove the bg image, the motion of my pman image is fluid. When the bg is on the canvas, the movement of pman is sluggish.

Comment: I get similar result whether there is background image or not.  Actually you don't need to use two loop variables (`leftLoop` and `rightLoop`), just use one for both left and right loop is enough.

Comment: Good point on only one loop variable. Thank you for that.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated my post with a small example. Do you have any suggestions?